# How to persist Twitter stream data to Postgres database using Spring Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am new to Spring Spring Boot, and Spring Cloud Dataflow. I am currently working on a POC and the goal is to load and persist streaming data into a relational database(as opposed to a batch job in traditional ETL).

I had successfully set up the stack for Spring Cloud Dataflow with [the official docker-compose file](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/). And I was able to follow the example on streaming and doing [analytics on twitter streams](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-data-flow-samples-twitter-analytics-overview). However since I don't have a deep enough understanding of this, I am not able to figure out how to persist these streams of data into a relational database (Postgres for example). Can anyone give me some hints on where to start? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [JDBC Sink app starter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/jdbc/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-jdbc).

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Gary had pointed out in the other answer, there are several examples of writing data to different datastores such as MySQL, Cassandra, and Gemfire.

See: [Spring Cloud Data Flow Samples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_http_to_mysql_demo)

You can use them as a reference.